# Download file via FTP, write to /tmp/ and output .txt contents to the console with AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fs

I am using just a single Node package, `basic-ftp` to try and download a TXT file and write the contents to the console. Further down the line I will be editing the text so will need to use `fs`. Just struggling to work with the output from `createWriteStream` from within the FTP program.

Can anyone help me write a TXT file to the /tmp/ file within AWS Lambda and then the correct syntax to open and edit the file after `createWriteStream` has been used?

```
var fs = require('fs');
const ftp = require("basic-ftp")
var path = require('path');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

var fullPath = "/home/example/public_html/_uploads/15_1_5c653e6f6780f.txt"; //  File Name FULL PATH -------
const extension = path.extname(fullPath); // Used to calculate filenames below
const wooFileName = path.basename(fullPath, extension); // Uploaded filename  with no path or extension eg. filename
const myFileNameWithExtension = path.basename(fullPath); // Uploaded filename  with the file extension eg. filename.txt
const FileNameWithExtension = path.basename(fullPath); // Uploaded filename  with the file extension eg. filename.txt

example()

async function example() {
    const client = new ftp.Client()
    client.ftp.verbose = true
    try {
        await client.access({
            host: "XXXX",
            user: "XXXX",
            password: "XXXX",
            //secure: true
        })
        await client.download(fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/' + myFileNameWithExtension), myFileNameWithExtension)
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    client.close()
}

//Read the content from the /tmp directory to check it's empty
fs.readdir("/tmp/", function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log('Contents of AWS Lambda /tmp/ directory');
});

/*
downloadedFile = fs.readFile('./tmp/' + myFileNameWithExtension)
console.log(downloadedFile)
console.log("Raw text:\n" + downloadedFile.Body.toString('ascii'));
*/

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure your `fs.createWriteStream()` has to use an absolute path to `/tmp` in Lambdas. Your actual working directory is `var/task` not `/`.

Also, if you're using [fs.createWriteStream()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) you'll need to wait for the `finish` event before reading from the file. Somethign like this...

```
async function example() {
    var finalData = '';

    const client = new ftp.Client()
    client.ftp.verbose = true
    try {
        await client.access({
            host: "XXXX",
            user: "XXXX",
            password: "XXXX",
            //secure: true
        })

        let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + myFileNameWithExtension);
        await client.download(writeStream, myFileNameWithExtension)

      await finalData = (()=>{
       return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {

        writeStream
          .on('finish', ()=>{
           fs.readFile("/tmp/"+myFileNameWithExtension, function (err, data) {
             if (err) { 
               reject(err) 
             } else {
               console.log('Contents of AWS Lambda /tmp/ directory', data);
               resolve(data);
             }
           });
          })
          .on('error', (err)=> {
             console.log(err);
             reject(err);
          })
        })
       })();
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    client.close();
    return finalData;
}
```

You'll also need to access the `file` using [fs.readFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback). What you were using [fs.readdir()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) gives you a list of files in the directory, not the file's contents.

If you want to used readdir() you could do it like this, but as you can see it is redundant in your case. To handle errors I would suggest just handling the `error` event in the initial `createWriteStream()` instead of adding this extra overhead *(added to previous example)*...

```
       writeStream
          .on('finish', ()=>{
           fs.readdir('/tmp',(err, files)=> {
               let saved = files.find(file => file === myFileNameWithExtension);
               fs.readFile("/tmp/"+saved, function (err, data) {
                 if (err) throw new Error();
                 console.log(data);
                 console.log('Contents of AWS Lambda /tmp/ directory');
               });
           })
          })
          .on('error', (err)=> {
             console.log(err);
             throw new Error();
          })
```

NOTE: Please log out the result of `saved`, I can't remember if the `files` array is absolute of relative paths.

Comment: This is brilliant, that's working in /tmp/ now. Do you know how I could edit the text and output to the console? I am currently getting ```Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined```

Comment: Oops yup, I missed that initially. You need to use  [fs.readFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback), not [fs.readdir()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) in this situation. Or you could use fs.readdir() then access the file content, but would be redundant if you just set the path... just updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The readdir() is used to output the /tmp/ contents to check the file had downloaded and is stored in tmp. What I wanted to do afterward was work with the txt file and also output its contents to the console such as ```//console.log("Raw text:\n" + data.Body.toString('ascii'));``` but after trying many variants I always get ```Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined```

Comment: Well using the `.on('finish',` will ensure the file has been written successfully so no need to do the readdir(). Try it with the modifications I made first, but if you really want to access the file paths first I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: That works a treat, content outputs using ```console.log("Raw text:\n" + data.toString('ascii'));``` - how can I access ```data``` outside of the async FTP function though? I tried setting ```var outside = data;``` within the FTP function after the console logs

Comment: Ah, yup I figured we would get here eventually... you'll need to wrap those nested `fs` callbacks in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and the call the `resolve()` method on successful completion. Mind you this code is getting pretty ugly and its not I would organize it I were starting from scratch, but should do the trick... (updated the first example to include Promise)

Comment: And note... given the above update your final data will be available in the result of `example()` but since it is returning a Promise you'll need to await it and convert your initial `handler` an async function... `const veryFinalData = await example();`.... and `exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {`

Comment: Or you could just do this `example().then(finalData=> callback(finalData))`